# How to send whether a face is detected via open cv to serial?

Tags: python, opencv, arduino, pyserial

I am trying to make a system where a python program sends a number (1 or 0) based on whether a face is detected or not using open cv. A arduino is then to recieve a signal and turn on or off a relay to turn on or off a light. I have done the part where the face is detected and the arduino but i want to know how i can make the python code send a 0 or 1. Here is the code:

```
import cv2

# Load the cascade
face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')

# To capture video from webcam.
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
# To use a video file as input
# cap = cv2.VideoCapture('filename.mp4')

while True:
    # Read the frame
    _, img = cap.read()
    # Convert to grayscale
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    # Detect the faces
    faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.1, 4)
    # Draw the rectangle around each face
    for (x, y, w, h) in faces:
        cv2.rectangle(img, (x, y), (x+w, y+h), (255, 0, 0), 2)
    # Display
    cv2.imshow('img', img)
    # Stop if escape key is pressed
    k = cv2.waitKey(30) & 0xff
    if k==27:
        break
# Release the VideoCapture object
cap.release()
```

I tried some things but they all failed miserably. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I see no evidence of even a rudimentary attempt at serial communication, just a piece of code copied verbatim from https://aiplanet.com/blog/face-detection-in-2-minutes-using-opencv-python/ (or possibly some other site that duplicates it). Surely you must have at least found a library to use, and figured out how to import it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [cv::CascadeClassifier detectMultiScale:](https://docs.opencv.org/4.6.0/d1/de5/classcv_1_1CascadeClassifier.html#aaf8181cb63968136476ec4204ffca498) method returns all the faces detected by OpenCV, so if there are no faces, the result `faces` will be empty.

You can test it, and do what you want accordingly :

```py
# ...
    # Detect the faces
    faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.1, 4)

    if len(face) == 0:
        # No face : turn on the light !
    else:
        # Something detected, lets do something...
```

For how to write from Python to the Arduino, you can use [pyserial](https://pyserial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/shortintro.html) :

```py
import time
import serial

ser = serial.Serial('/dev/serial0', 115200, timeout=0.050)

# ...

if len(face) == 0:
    # No face
    ser.open()
    ser.write('0')
    time.sleep(1)
    ser.close()
else:
    # A least one face detected
    ser.open()
    ser.write('1')
    time.sleep(1)
    ser.close()
```

As you see, the if and else part can be factorized, etc. :-)